# Although all repo permission are on allow the user can't access it

Tags: azure-devops

I have one admin user which is the admin of the project and another user. I have given the second user all the permission required for the repo but still can't access it...

Permissions:
[Permissions image capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9pn4.png)

Tools bar in second users account:
[Tools bar image capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9yTm.png)

I have tried giving every kind of permission to that user but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Your user uses `Stakeholder access level`. Change it to `Basic level` on the organization settings:

[image]

---

[image]